# Replace .php with .asp for all urls (inc subdomains)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, s3-rewrite-rules

I tried to find a solution and used the search here, but unfortunately all the variants I could find did not work in my case. I need your help please.
For example, I have a site.com and subdomains (wildcard). All pages have a .php extension.
How can I change the .php extension to .asp for all pages in the browser? **For example when I open sub.site.com/page.php page in the browser I need it to look like sub.site.com/page.asp**
Please note, all subdomains are located in subdirectories. This is an example of a line from site.com.conf file
`VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html/%1/`

This is my current .htaccess file but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1.php [L]
```

I have tried different options for .htassess - but none of the options work.

I also tried this option, but it doesn't work either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Why on searth would one want to do that?

Comment: So what does "does not work" actually mean? Does the process crash? Do you get an error? Do you get a "wrong" result?

Comment: The rewriting rules you posted indeed won't work. Look at your second condition: you only want to apply the actual rule if a request to something ending with ".asp" points to a file ending with ".php" if you append  ".php" to what is requested. But are your actual file names really ending in ".asp.php"?

Comment: @arkascha File Extensions is .php. NOT ".asp.php".

Comment: Yes, I would expect that. But that condition you implemented tests for a file with the file ending ".asp.php". Which is why your rule never gets applied.

Comment: @arkascha do you know how to fix this?